# How to create passwordfield or hide the password inside table view

Tags: java, javafx-2

Here i am creating one TableView  and displaying data in that TableView by passing ObservableList.
Here observable list is taken from the database.And shown in the table view in Name-Value columns.
Here some passwords are also present in the data.So, how to hide these password fields from user?

Comment: Why don't just you hash the password, so that you won't have to used masking of password whenever you want display the password.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cell factory with a PasswordField on it.

First, you have to set the cell factory.

```
tableColumnPass.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<YourTableBean,String>, TableCell<YourTableBean,String>>() {         
        @Override
        public TableCell<YourTableBean, String> call(TableColumn<YourTableBean, String> cell) {
            return new PasswordFieldCell();
        }
    });
```

And in your PasswordFieldCell, you can have the next code, setting in the graphic of the cell a password field in the update item method.

```
public class PasswordFieldCell extends TableCell<YourTableBean, String> {
private PasswordField passwordField;    
public PasswordFieldCell() {
    passwordField = new PasswordField();
    passwordField.setEditable(false);
    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    this.setGraphic(null);
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if(!isEmpty()){
        passwordField.setText(item);
        setGraphic(passwordField);
    }else{
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}}
```

If you don't have a Bean, you still can do this. Just need to change the cellfactory of the specific column.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a label can do it better.. (Based in @Antonio J. response)

```
public class PasswordLabelCell extends TableCell<YourTableBean, String> {
    private Label label;

    public PasswordLabelCell() {
        label = new Label();
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.setGraphic(null);
    }

    private String genDotString(int len) {
        String dots = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            dots += "\u2022";
        }

        return dots;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            label.setText(genDotString(item.length()));
            setGraphic(label);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And now set column cell factory

```
myPasswordColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new PasswordLabelCell());
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this ready to use class for password cells that supports editing.

```java
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

/**
 *
 * @author Rami Manaf Abdullah
 */
public class PasswordFieldTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> forTableColumn() {
        return forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter());
    }

    public static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> forTableColumn(StringConverter<T> converter) {
        return (param) -> {
            return new PasswordFieldTableCell<S, T>(converter);
        };
    }

    private StringConverter<T> converter;
    private PasswordField passwordField;
    private Label text;
    
    public PasswordFieldTableCell(StringConverter<T> converter) {
        super();
        this.converter = converter;
        passwordField = new PasswordField();
        passwordField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        passwordField.setOnAction(event -> {
            commitEdit(converter.fromString(passwordField.getText()));
            event.consume();
        });
        passwordField.setOnKeyReleased(t -> {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
                t.consume();
            }
        });
        text = new Label();
        text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        text.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                passwordField.setText(item.toString());
                setGraphic(passwordField);
            } else {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(item.toString().length());
                for (int i = 0; i < item.toString().length(); i++) {
                    builder.append('\u2022');
                }
                text.setText(builder.toString());
                setGraphic(text);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEditable()
                || !getTableView().isEditable()
                || !getTableColumn().isEditable()) {
            return;
        }
        super.startEdit();

        if (isEditing()) {
            passwordField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
            setGraphic(passwordField);
            passwordField.selectAll();
            passwordField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setGraphic(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I visited this while searching for a solution. However, the suggested methods do not show how to update the field.

My solution is quite simple. Use a textfield. While populating the ObservableList, just replace the text with  ******